# Dropdown menu item value not coming in the Email subject

Tags: orbeon

From Orbeon(4.6) builder , I selected 'show in Email subject' option for the dropdown menu control in my form.
When I send the email, the dropdown item value is not showing in the email subject.

I tried with all other controls like 'input','checkbox', 'radio button' etc, all are working perfectly fine. ie The Email subject is populating with these control values. Problem is only with 'dropdown menu' control

Is this a bug or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

For reference this was a bug and has since beeen [fixed](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2036).